# How to move an object with hot keys in Maya python

Tags: python, move, maya, hotkeys, autodesk

well I got this piece of code-

```
def moveCurrent(direction):
    getSel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
    if getSel:
        if direction == "up":
            currentVal = cmds.getAttr("%s.tx" % getSel[0])
            cmds.setAttr("%s.tx" % getSel[0], currentVal + 10)
        elif direction == "down":
            currentVal = cmds.getAttr("%s.tx" % getSel[0])
            cmds.setAttr("%s.tx" % getSel[0], currentVal - 10)
        elif direction == "left":
            currentVal = cmds.getAttr("%s.tz" % getSel[0])
            cmds.setAttr("%s.tz" % getSel[0], currentVal - 10)
        elif direction == "right":
            currentVal = cmds.getAttr("%s.tz" % getSel[0])
            cmds.setAttr("%s.tz" % getSel[0], currentVal + 10)

cmds.nameCommand( 'moveCurrentSelectionFuncUp', ann='Move Selected Mode', c='python("moveCurrent(\\\"up\\\")")' )
cmds.nameCommand( 'moveCurrentSelectionFuncDown', ann='Move Selected Mode b', c='python("moveCurrent(\\\"down\\\")")' )
cmds.nameCommand( 'moveCurrentSelectionFuncLeft', ann='Move Selected Mode c ', c='python("moveCurrent(\\\"left\\\")")' )
cmds.nameCommand( 'moveCurrentSelectionFuncRight', ann='Move Selected Mode d ', c='python("moveCurrent(\\\"right\\\")")' )
cmds.hotkey( keyShortcut='F5', name='moveCurrentSelectionFuncUp' )      
cmds.hotkey( keyShortcut='F6', name='moveCurrentSelectionFuncDown' ) 
cmds.hotkey( keyShortcut='F7', name='moveCurrentSelectionFuncLeft' ) 
cmds.hotkey( keyShortcut='F8', name='moveCurrentSelectionFuncRight' )
```

this code works only if I call the function and enter a direction into it.
How ever, I want the object to move if I just press the hot keys, I dont want to call the function manually, I want it to happen if the specified hot key is pressed - if F5 is pressed, so the object moves up..it can be any other hot key. 
Is it possible?

Comment: This works as written: selecting something and pressing f5 -f8 moves the object. However it is not continuous - you need to press the key multiple times

Comment: So how can I make it continuous?

Comment: You can't, not without hacking the main maya QT window.  Maya only reacts to presses and releases

Comment: Do you know how to hack it  ? Is it legal?

Comment: @theodox        Well I tried it without writing the function, how ever, it doesnt move even a little bit, and I pressed like 100 times

Comment: a) It's legal, but not trivial:  You need to learn how to work with QT signals and intercept them.  You might find somebody at tech-artists.org who knows how.  b) the code above works if you execute the whole thing once - for the duration of that session f5-f8 will move selected objects.  Because you use setAttr instead of xform  it only works on objects (not components)

Comment: @theodox        so you are telling me that there is no way to create games in Maya, that need pressing like that? without hacking the software?

Comment: @theodox        The QT is a software isn't it? Do you know how can I hack it into Maya?

Comment: well maya is not a game engine so its hard to do it. And hacking QT events also will not be that successful. And if you copy a code from another question link it

Comment: The closest you could do to creating a game inside of maya would be to use the motion capture API to create a plugin that would do live updates. I think that only works while animations are playing, however.  If you want to make a game use Maya to make the content but program it in Unity

Comment: @theodox       do you know if there is an option to - make an object move while I long press the hotkey in Maya LT ? because I did that and it worked only when I pressed and left the button over and over again.

Comment: That's what I mean: press and release, but no hold in Maya.

Comment: Copying answer from another question and pasting to another thread without link is not a fair job :). And if the answer help'd you then upvote that.